# FindMinimum for a large range

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I have a function `functionSL[0.01,zl,zh]` where I want to find at which `zl` its minimum value occurs for each different `zh`. I already know at which `zl` is the minimum for each `zh` since I calculated it using `FindMinimum` for each one. The problem now is that I want to use `Table` to calculate them all at the same time.

My code is as follows

```
d = 3;
toroot[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := a - ((2 zl Sqrt[(1 + t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1)^-1])/((d + 1) (zl/zh)^(d + 1))) NIntegrate[(x)/Sqrt[(1 - x^2) (1 - (((1 + t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1)^-1) (zl/zh)^-6) x^3)], {x, 0, (zl/zh)^2}, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
tz[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := t /. FindRoot[toroot[a, t, zl, zh], {t, -15, -20, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 12]
intSL1[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := ((-1/(d - 1)) (zl^(2 d) (1 + tz[a, zl, zh]^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1))^-1 zl^(2 d))*NIntegrate[x^d ((1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1) x^(d + 1))/(1 - (zl^(2 d) (1 + tz[a, zl, zh]^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1))^-1 (zl x)^(2 d)))^(1/2), {x, 10^-8, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]
intSL2[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := ((-(zl/zh)^(d + 1) (d + 1))/(2 (d - 1))) * NIntegrate[x ((1 - (zl^(2 d) (1 + tz[a, zl, zh]^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1))^-1 (zl x)^(2 d))/(1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1) x^(d + 1)))^(1/2), {x, 10^-8, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]
intSL3[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := (zl/zh)^(d + 1) * NIntegrate[x/((1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1) x^(d + 1)) (1 - (zl^(2 d) (1 + tz[a, zl, zh]^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1))^-1 (zl x)^(2 d)))^(1/2), {x, 10^-8, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]
functionSL[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := ((-((1 - (zl^(2 d) (1 + tz[a, zl, zh]^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1))^-1 zl^(2 d)) (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1)))^(1/2)/(d - 1)) + intSL1[a, zl, zh] + intSL2[a, zl, zh] + intSL3[a, zl, zh] + 1)/(4 zl^(d - 1))
```

One issue is that every time I change `zh` I also need to change the parameter `t` in the `FindRoot`,

```
tz[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := t /. FindRoot[toroot[a, t, zl, zh], {t, -15, -20, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 12]
```

I already know that the minimum always occurs around `~0.93*zh`, an example would be, for `zh=1` the minimum is at `zl=0.930685`. Now if you plot `tz[0.01,zl,1]` you will see the corresponding `t` you need to put in `FindRoot` for it to find a solution.

[image: Image1]

You can see that `zl=0.930685` is around `t=-15` so that is why I set that as the starting point in `FindRoot`. The same goes for all other `zh`.

The code for finding the minimum for `zh=1` is,

```
FindMinimum[functionSL[0.01, zl, 1], {zl, 0.8, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10, MaxIterations -> 100] // Quiet
{0.216556, {zl -> 0.930685}}
```

If I do it for all `zh` at the same time I have,

```
In[39]:= Zmin = Table[FindMinimum[{functionSL[0.01, zl, zh], zl <= zh}, {zl, 0.9, 0.8, 100}], {zh, {1, 5, 10, 50, 100}}] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming

Out[39]= {268.65, {{0.216556, {zl -> 0.930685}}, {0.00866033, {zl -> 4.653}}, {0.00216507, {zl -> 9.30576}}, {0.0000874471, {zl -> 44.7789}}, {0.0000326264, {zl -> 64.6718}}}}
```

You see that for smaller `zh` I got the correct values for `zl` but for higher `zh` like `zh=100` you see that the result is not correct. Also you see that I used `0.9` as a starting point. The problem has to do with what I put in `FindRoot`, I think.

```
FindRoot[toroot[a, t, zl, zh], {t, -15, -20, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 12]
```

putting `{t, -15, -20, 0}` makes it more likely that I find the correct roots for lower `zh`, but not so for higher.

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding  your problem, I changed the initial conditions to `{zl, .8 zh, 0.9 zh}` and   tried

```
Table[{zh, zl /. FindMinimum[functionSL[0.01, zl, zh],
{zl, .8 zh, 0.9 zh}][[2]]}
, {zh, {.8,1.1, 10, 20, 100}}] // Quiet 
(*{{0.8, 0.744584}, {1.1, 1.02374}, {10, 9.3059}, {20, 18.6118}, {100, 93.059}}*)
```

which gives tabeled result `{zh,zl}`up to  `zh=100`.

Comment: Could you explain why changing the range in `FindMinimum` as you wrote works as compared to what I used which is the beginner's way.

Comment: The starting values for `zl` in   `FindMinimum` now depend on `zh` which forces a solution zl near zh (perhaps).

Comment: Thank you very much! Did not know it was that simple.